# LLDB extended documentation

Tags: lldb

Where can I find an extended list of options for LLDB?

For example: the --auto-continue option, shown in the tutorial does not appear in the help command (`help br set`):
https://lldb.llvm.org/use/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--auto-continue` flag is a somewhat recent addition to lldb, so if you have an older lldb, you might not have it.  In the current TOT lldb, and the most recent Xcode version, both have the option, e.g.:

```
(lldb) version
lldb-1500.0.22.8
Apple Swift version 5.9 (swiftlang-5.9.0.128.108 clang-1500.0.40.1)
(lldb) help break set
Sets a breakpoint or set of breakpoints in the executable.

Syntax: breakpoint set <cmd-options>

...

       -G <boolean> ( --auto-continue <boolean> )
            The breakpoint will auto-continue after running its commands.
```